# Forcing a monadic computation to be done statically

Tags: haskell, recursion, inline, ghc

In [Matthew Pickering's blog post about inlining](https://mpickering.github.io/posts/2017-03-20-inlining-and-specialisation.html), he mentions a trick to force GHC to inline recursive definitions applied to a statically known argument:

> However, there is a trick that can be used in order to tell GHC that an argument is truly static. We replace the value argument with a type argument. Then by defining suitable type class instances, we can recurse on the structure of the type as we would on a normal value. This time however, GHC will happily inline each “recursive” call as each call to sum is at a different type.

Then the blog post proceeds to show a very simplistic example using type-level `Nat`s. My question is about forcing GHC to fully inline functions over actually interesting types.

In my case, I have a computation that is via a monadic DSL. Under the hood, the DSL is an `RWS`. Looking at the generated Core with lots of `INLINE` pragmas, I can see calls to the recursive functions that implement `<>` for the writer output. Since these functions are recursive, GHC doesn't inline them. But if it did, since the full RWS computation is static enough that the spine of the writer output could be fully unrolled during compilation, it would, after finitely many steps, arrive at Core with no recursive definitions left.

Taking the idea from Matt's blog post, we would need to have a type-level representation of the monadic value; I'd love to see a version of this (especially with good ergonomics!), but I am not too optimistic: unlike the Servant approach, we would need a way to bind variables to results (a la monadic `>>=`). Alternatively, are there any other mechanisms to tell GHC that its input size is statically known, so it shouldn't shy away from aggressively inlining recrusive definitions? For example, is it possible to emulate Agda-style [sized types](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1.1/language/sized-types.html) by using a graded monad with some appropriate size measure in the index?

P.s.: My aim is not mere optimization, but [working around a Clash bug](https://github.com/clash-lang/clash-compiler/issues/1536), so this elimination of recursive definitions by aggressive inlining would need to be something dependable, not a nice-to-have performance improvement.

Comment: I don't know how to convince GHC to relyably perform that optimization, but if everything fails maybe one could use Template Haskell to run code at compile time.

Comment: @chi: yes, that is exactly what I am doing (in fact, I  plan to write a blog post about this whole ordeal...), but I am very unhappy with the ergonomics of the TH solution.

Comment: @chi compare the two examples at https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/d4c37fd4798786c61557a8144e814bf6 the non-TH version requires less type annotations, and has no special syntax for special arguments that can be dynamic (i.e. the things inside `[| |]` in the TH version)

Comment: @chi and this is even before we get to things like factoring out parts of a memory map, where the TH staging restriction becomes a huge nuissance.

Comment: I expect one of the most difficult bits of lifting `RWS` is representing first-class functions at the type level (since after all `RWS r w s a` is actually the function type `r -> s -> (w, s, a)` or something like that). For that, you might check out [first-class-families](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/first-class-families). (A full answer would likely need much more legwork.)

Comment: @DanielWagner and what about the user-defined functions coming from binds? If the user is expected to defunctionalize himself, I might as well just go TH...

Comment: @Cactus You're not obligated to *like* the answer... but it might be the answer nevertheless.

Comment: @DanielWagner too bad I can't say "I'm looking for all kinds of free-form ideation" because then it wouldn't be on-topic on SO...

Comment: @DanielWagner FWIW I am not married to RWS, it was just the easiest way to get it working modulo the whole inlining nonsense. So if other impl strategies would work, I'd be happy. But there's still the issue of binds. One thing I've been thinking of is passing vars around as just `Symbol`s, and then some instance would simply be missing if you refer to a "variable" not in scope.

Comment: Fine-grained control on inlining is a missing feature that is just waiting for a motivated contributor to implement. Implementing annotations to "expose the unfolding of this recursive function" and "inline this call recursively" is a pretty well-defined task.